# prevAll() and filter by child presence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following (artificial) DOM:

```
<div class="something">xxx</div>
<div class="something">
  <div class="essence">yyy</div>
</div>
<div class="something">zzz</div>
<div class="something">
  <div class="essence">111</div>
</div>
```

Then in `$(document).ready` I do:

```
$('.essence').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().prevAll('.something > .essence').toggle();
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.something > .essence').toggle();
});
```

It does not seem to work..

Basically, I want to hide/show all preceding and following siblings of clicked element's **parent**, which do not contain a child with the same class as the clicked element.

Please help. Apologies if this seems vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highlighted the important parts of your requirement:

> I want to **hide** all preceding and following **siblings** of clicked element **parent**, which do **not contain** a child with the **same class as the clicked element**.

which would translate to

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not(':has(> .' + this.className + ')').hide();
```

or

```
var className = this.className;
$(this).parent().siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('.' + className).length === 0;
}).hide();
```

---

Explanation for why your code does not work:

`.prevAll` and `.nextAll` get the preceding for following siblings of an element, **if and only if** they match the selector. In your case, all the siblings have class `something`. The selector doesn't match any of them because it only matches elements with class `essence` that are children of elements with class `something`.
I understand what you tried to do, but that's not how those methods work.

Comment: Cool, this works! I only had to change `hide()` to `toggle` as I want to toggle the visibility

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('.essence').click(function()
{
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).parent().siblings().filter(function(){
        return !$(this).children('.'+className).length;
    }).toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/LkD3J/1/)

Comment: I may try this, unless it has syntax error: `lenght`. Anyway, in jsfiddle it works so that it hides also previous `.something` with `.essence` child

Comment: @RomanSaveljev, my bad, fixed the typo but thanks for reminding me :-)

Comment: @RomanSaveljev, Sorry for not testing the code properly but it works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :has() extension like this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.something:has(.essence)').toggle();
```

This will select all siblings of .parent() that are of class .something and contain a descendant of class .essence. You can alternatively do this, which according to the documentation may be faster:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.something').has('.essence').toggle();
```

It's sort of a weird behaviour when I see it in action, so it's hard to know if it's exactly what you need. If you want to toggle all siblings which DO NOT have a child of the class .essence then try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.something').not(':has(.essence)').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed to something as under:

```
$('.essence').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().siblings().not(':has("> div")').toggle();
});
```